# Seamless mouse operation across dual monitors - 1 landscape & 1 portrait

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm trying to put together a quad monitor setup with two monitors in landcape mode (stacked), sandwiched between 2 monitors in portrait mode (one on each side).  I currently have 3 of the 4 planned monitors and have been testing to see if this is possible before I get the fourth and the appropriate stand.  When testing, I have no problem changing one of the monitors to portrait mode.  However, when I do this the mouse operation for the portrait monitor still seems to think it's in landscape mode - move mouse up, cursor goes left; move mouse right, cursor goes down....

Is there a way to configure the mouse to work seamlessly across all monitors?

I have the following:
Windows 8
2 ea., GeForce GT610 graphics card  Driver version 320.49

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried win 8.1 they improved multi monitor support even more